# Manage/Organize Workflows & Alerts

Tags: administration, workflow, email-alert

Has anyone come up with a good process for organizing and managing workflow rules and alerts?

I recently joined my current company, and part of my job is to take over as the Salesforce administrator.  I'm new to Salesforce.  The previous Salesforce admin(s) created hundreds of workflow rules and associated e-mail alerts.  These have to stay, because our employees depend on these alerts for their business processes.

It's a nightmare every time someone wants me to change an alert.  The latest example is due to a newly hired employee.  His manager wants the new guy to receive the "timecard e-mail."  There are nearly 100 workflow rules associated with the timecard custom object!

As time permits, I'm going to clean up our pile of Salesforce spaghetti.  Has anyone encountered the same problem and come up with a good scheme to keep things sane?

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem in any serious salesforce.com organization. The tools provided are scant, but there are things you can do:

1. Use a naming convention. This sounds too simple to be useful, but renaming your rules so that they reflect what they do will make life easier.
2. Use descriptions. Come up with a system to put keywords into the description to make it easy to find them, and help you (and those that follow) determine what a rule does without deciphering filters.
3. Armed with properly named and described rules, make list views. For example, you could make a list view for "Object equals TimeCard__c AND Description contains For:HumanResources" (here assuming that For:HumanResources is a keyword). For more kick, you can also use "Active equals true" as a filter to keep inactive rules from cluttering up the list.

Unfortunately, that's about all you can do "within the system." I'd also likely recommend a document stored in the Documents tab that's updated periodically with the rules that are present, the business process that calls for the rule, who requested the rule, and who uses the rule. Your description field gets 255 characters, so you might create a system like this: <tag>:<value>;...

For example, if human resources wants to make sure that the Eastern Division Sales Associates don't accumulate more than 10 hours of overtime in a time period, you might write the description as this:

```
REQ:HR,FOR:EasternSales,WHY:Notify when over 10 hours OT.
```

This is just one possibility, others are definitely possible. The problem lies with the human tendency to not document things correctly (a.k.a. laziness). Make up a system and stick with it, and you'll be fine.